# Allow network connection to a specifc app

Tags: networking, proxy, iphone, android

I am developing a application for mobile (iPhone and Android) maps based for a company. The company has deployed a wifi network to allow, by subscribing (paying), internet access.

The idea of the mobile app is to give internet access only to that specific app to any ones that have it. In other words, company wants to allow to application to connect to this network, so  users can see some information using the internet service without having a pay plan, only to know some basic information about the company and its services.

My question is: is it possible to give access only to a specific application and what would be the most appropriate way? Is the app that "recognize" that network or network is in charge of give access to that specific app, for example by a proxy server that requires authentication?

Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The approach to handle this on the clients seems strange to me. You control the WiFi network. People have to login somehow. Thus it seems obvious to me to limit access in the WiFi routers to the systems (your servers) which shall be accessible for non-subscribers, too. During the login process you check the status of the user and depending on that status you may reconfigure the router to allow Internet access to this user.

Comment: The wifi network is accessible by a web-based login form by users that have pay for use the internet access. The idea is that an user with that app, without having an user a password can access to the network  only by the app fos some basic use like see a map with company markplaces.